# How to create a downward arrow using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have tried creating a **white downward arrow** using the HTML code `&#8681;` that renders as this: ⇩.
However I could not fill it and there comes a lot of space above and below the arrow.

How can I create the same by using **CSS**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body{font-size:30px;}
i.arrow-down{
  color: #f0f;
  width:  0.5em;
  height:  0.7em;
  display:  inline-block;
  position:  relative;
  background:  currentColor;
  vertical-align: top;
} i.arrow-down:after{
  border-right:  0.5em solid transparent;
  border-left:  0.5em solid transparent;
  border-top:  0.4em solid currentColor;
  position:  absolute;
  content:  "";
  bottom:  -0.3em;
  left:  -0.22em;
}
```

```html
Arrow Down <i class="arrow-down"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code for the down arrow ↓ is `&#8595;`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a lot of work to me, have you considered using icons perhaps? Then you'd have the ability to size them, color them, transform them, etc.

http://fontawesome.io/icons/